# How to store countries and states name in android app

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I am making an android app in which I need data of countries and states of countries. I may also need names of districts of these countries. So in all I have lot of structured data.

According to my use case, I want to frequently access this data.

So what is the best way to store such large data in android app.

Thanks

Comment: SQLite,  Why are you even hesitating?

Comment: @Simon
I was thinking in terms of constant file.
Thank you very much :)

Comment: Doesn't make a difference if constant or not.  Large amount of structured data with frequent access.  There is no other choice that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If your file's content doesn't change, you can use a res/values/country file.

Comment: It won't change surely but I am asking how to store this data in  structured way so it is easy in fetching.

Comment: So I have one country as parent then its child has list of states and each state child is list of district

Comment: You can use String for parent and String-array for its child.